# Could accessing array element outside boundary corrupt it

Tags: c++, arrays, undefined-behavior

Is it possible that accessing an array outside its boundary corrupt its existing elements

```
MyObject* array[10];

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    array[i] = nullptr;
}
array[1] = new MyObject();
array[8] = new MyObject();
array[15] = new MyObject();
```

could accessing array[15] result in the corruption of the elements between 0-10?

Comment: Accessing `array[15]` could spawn a dragons in your room, I guess corrupting elements 0-10 is also possible.

Comment: I have noticed, that the most common manifestation of UB is that code works as intended, but only when boss is not looking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> could accessing `array[15]` result in the corruption of the elements between 0-10?

Yes. This is undefined behavior, and the nature of UB is that *anything* can happen. In particular, it usually doesn't make much sense to reason about what *could* happen or what is more likely to happen. It can be anything, including the corruption of some array elements that were intact before UB.